# Set session from rails model without being evil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am playing around with http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch and bumped into a problem when trying to do a little refactor.

The app logs a user in by simply setting:

```
session[:user_id] = user.id
```

Currently this sits in the controller. I would simply like to have two methods on the User object. One called login and one called logout. It means if I change the implementation of being logged in then there is only one place to change the code and also makes it slightly more readable. The simplest solution would obviously be to simply add this to the user model:

```
def login
  session[:user_id] = user.id
end
```

As we all know sessions are not accessible in rails models. We could obviously create the two methods on the application controller and pass in the user object but that seems a little ugly, what is the recommended way of achieving this simple usecase?

Comment: methods defined in ApplicationController are availabe in all controllers, no duplication here

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to not put code like that in the model.

I realize that this doesn't answer the actual question but there is no recommended way to implement this within the model. Models are for database access only and they should not be used to interact with the http session by themselves.

Recognizing and maintaining a 'current_user' is the clear responsability of controllers (within the MVC pattern).

Comment: Yes, but it really is more readable and maintainable to have it in a method rather than just the login and logout logic pasted around various places. Is the best place really just two methods on the application controller where you pass in the user object?

Comment: @Nick: can't understand why you state the code would be duplicated.

Comment: If I wanted to log out a user in various parts of the application then I would have various places where it said something like "session[:user_id] = nil" - Its not a big issue but its just not that clear to another user exactly what that does either.

Comment: @Nick Wouldn't you put that in a helper?

Comment: That would work but it doesnt really belong there. From my understanding helpers are more suited for small view helper scripts.

Comment: put it as a method in the application controller. Use that method in before filters or wherever across your various controllers.

Comment: My point is that by obeying MVC, there should be no other place within your application where you would want to `session[:user_id] = nil`. If you totally have to, you could add a method to your controller and then add `helper_method :login, :logout` to that same controller. This would make the method available from within views.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to give the User a class, class instance, or proc that can do login/logout.

The user class only needs to call a class method/proc, all details about *how* login/logout happens are encapsulated in the class/proc.

This also isolates the login/logout *idea* from Rails, so the same model could be used from a GUI app (e.g., JRuby/Swing) or a command-line app. How easy/difficult that is depends on your models as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can raise an Exception in the model and catch it in the Controller with a rescue_from. Similar to what you do with CanCan.